# Get different set of data based on value on two tables

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT users.firstname,
users.lastname,
users.username,
users.image_url,
posts.status,
posts.created_at as created_at,
posts.updated_at as updated_at,
share.post_user_id as user_id,
posts.id,
share.message as message,
share.user_id as share_user_id
FROM `share` INNER JOIN `posts` ON share.post_id = posts.id 
INNER JOIN `users` ON users.id = share.user_id
```

So, as you can see here, I'm getting the firstname, lastname, and username from the table users based on the users.id = share.user_id. The share table is like this:

Shares

- message
- user_id
- post_user_id
- post_id

Now how can I get the set of names based on users.id = share.post_user_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need  another inner join on table users  using an alias  eg user2

```
    SELECT users.firstname,
    users.lastname,
    users.username,
    users.image_url,
    posts.status,
    posts.created_at as created_at,
    posts.updated_at as updated_at,
    share.post_user_id as user_id,
    posts.id,
    share.message as message,
    share.user_id as share_user_id,
    users2.firstname,
    users2.lastname,
    users2.username,
    FROM `share` 
    INNER JOIN `posts` ON share.post_id = posts.id 
    INNER JOIN `users` ON users.id = share.user_id
    INNER JOIN `users`  AS user2 ON users2.id = post_user_id.user_id
```